# Minio: password change policy

Tags: amazon-iam, policy, minio

Is it possible to create a canned policy that prevents the user from changing the password?

minio:RELEASE.2020-06-22T03-12-50Z / Docker

Comment: MinIO is an object compatible storage, it provides an API for s3, you can set permissions on the bucket, but user management borders more on IAM roles, and I don't think it provides that.

Comment: It however does provide you with bucket permissions, put, post, delete etc-- but on the bucket.